# python: upload file via sftp from behind a socks5 proxy

Tags: python, proxy, sftp

I am trying to look for any sample code that would allow me to upload a file via sftp to a remote machine, with the condition we are behind a SOCKS5 Proxy.

I am trying to figure out if using paraproxy would do the job.